# Android OnLongClickListener issue

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

I have a custom view, DisView(Context, bitmap), which I want to add a LongCLickListener to.

The view is displayed once something else is clicked.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    ...
    RelativeLayout toplayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    setContentView(toplayout);

    Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tag3);

    tag3 = new DisView(this,bmp2);
    tag3.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

I should add that originally the activity's contentview is set to a linearlayout, but on a button being clicked, setContentLayout() makes a relativelayout the new layout.

Next I did the onLongClick method ( a method of the activity, implementing onlongclicklistener):

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

    moveTag(view);
    return true;
}
```

moveTag() is a very simple TranslateAnimation. I have no idea why it doesn't work. I have a feeling it may be because I changed the layout.

Comment: What "doesn't work" exactly? According to your code you don't add your DisView to your toplayout...

Comment: Sorry in my copy past rush job the addView() was lost. It works fine. Tag3 moves across the screen as I intended. Its just I can't longclick it. Ive actually done the sensible thing and started a new activity for this animation. But the same problem applies. longclick just refuses to work.

Answer (score 0):

did you think about ViewSwitcher to change your displayed layout?

Jonathan

Comment: I tried it, but it seemed to cause more problems than solve. Thanks for the help. I decided just to make a new Activity and put the second layout as the base layout for that. It hasnt really solved my onlongclick problem though.

Answer (score 0):

if toplayout is a LinearLayout and you write
  RelativeLayout toplayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
the software will usually crash on startup(or when this view is activated), if what you meet now is the software crashes once it started(or when you start this activity), it is highly possible that the problem is caused by this statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you did this:

```
tag3.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

Why did you do that?

**setOnLongClickListener** takes a parameter of type **OnLongClickLIstener**.  Something like:

```
tag3.setOnLongClickListener((OnLongClickListener) keyHdlr);
```

where keyHdlr looks something like this:

```
OnLongClickListener keyHdlr = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("long", "backspace phone land long clicked!!!!!!");
                    return false;
                }
            };
```